# Using activatedRout.snapshot in Angular Service

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, angular-services

I created this service in Angular that prevents an user with a id different from the one in the link to go to the page but idTemp is undefined.What I am doing wrong?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router,
  ActivatedRoute,
} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MeAdminGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ):
    | boolean
    | import('@angular/router').UrlTree
    | import('rxjs').Observable<boolean | import('@angular/router').UrlTree>
    | Promise<boolean | import('@angular/router').UrlTree> {
    var idTemp = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log('ID:', idTemp);
    if (
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).role == 'Admin' ||
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id == idTemp
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/homepage']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to read the ID from a service in the MeAdminGuardService class , and not to read it from this.route.snapshot.params['id'].